# El proceso devolvió ##### al ejecutar un programa hecho en C

Tags: c

Estoy liado con un programita que supuestamente es sencillo pero que me está dando algún problema.

En el programa en cuestión debo inicializar unos datos al comenzar el programa. Pero al declarar una variable para imprimir esos datos por pantalla me sale esto.
[image: Error]

El programa está escrito en C.

El error me sale al declarar un vector en el modulo de inicialización de los datos que os he comentado.

El código del modulo Almacén es este:

```
#pragma once
#include "Ges_Almacen.h"
#include "GestionPac_Ped.h"

const int calleAl = 48;
const int municipioAl = 48;
const int provinciaAl = 16;
const int descripAl = 48;

extern int numeroAl;

typedef int CodigoAlmacen;
typedef char CalleAlmacen[calleAl + 1];
typedef char MunicipioAlmacen[municipioAl + 1];
typedef char ProvinciaAlmacen[provinciaAl + 1];
typedef char DescripcionAl[descripAl + 1];


typedef struct TipoAlmacen {

    TipoVectPac Vectorpacientes;

    CodigoAlmacen codigo;
    CalleAlmacen calle;
    MunicipioAlmacen municipio;
    ProvinciaAlmacen provincia;
    DescripcionAl descripcion;

};

typedef TipoAlmacen TipoVecAlmacen[10];

typedef struct GesAlmacen {

  void AltaAlmacen(TipoAlmacen almacen);

};
```

Y el código de modulo de inicialización es:

```
#pragma once
#include "Ges_Almacen.h"
#include "GestionPac_Ped.h"

typedef struct iniciarGes{

    void iniGestion(TipoVecAlmacen almacenes);

};
```

y el de su implementación es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "iniciarGestion.h"

void listarIni(TipoVecAlmacen almacenes){

    int numeroAl = 10;

    printf("ListadoGesti%cn FarmaDron: \n\n",162);
    printf("Calle\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroAl; i++) {
    printf("\n\t%d\t%s %s\t  %5d\t   %4d", i + 1, almacenes[i].calle);

    printf("\n");
    }
}


void iniciarGes::iniGestion(TipoVecAlmacen almacenes) {

    TipoAlmacen almacen;
    int Codigo;


    strcpy(almacen.calle, "Virgen Filomena Nieves,21");
    strcpy(almacen.calle, "Madrid");
    //strcpy(almacen.provincia, "Madrid");
    //strcpy(almacen.descripcion, "Madrid Capital");

    listarIni(almacenes);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta esta redactada correctamente... esta es la forma de mostrar el codigo para que se pueda reproducir tu problema...

Comment: En  InitGestion no agregas al vector almacenes ningún almacen.

Comment: No entiendo lo que me dices, debo agregar los datos completos del almacén al vector?. El código que tengo es una prueba a ver si lograba que  funcionara.

Comment: Esta pregunta no debería usar la etiqueta de [c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), puesto en C no es posible declarar una función en una estructura. Mas bien estás mezclando código C con C++ (algo que no debería pasar).